# How may I find all primary keys in a database and their identity and seed values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The following query returns a listing of all my database primary keys and additional columns.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sysobjects AS s
WHERE   xtype='pk'
```

None of the aforementioned additional columns are related to a primary key's identity, seed value, increment value, etc.

What query should I use, or how may I find all primary keys in a database and their identity and seed values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATED**

(now uses `identity_columns` table instead of the `IDENT_...` functions)

```
SELECT  object_name(i.object_id) tableName,
        i.name indexName,
        c.name columnName,
        c.is_identity,
        idc.seed_value,
        idc.increment_value,
        idc.last_value
FROM sys.indexes i
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON  ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.identity_columns idc ON idc.object_id = c.object_id AND idc.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
```

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/23/sql-server-query-to-find-seed-values-increment-values-and-current-identity-column-value-of-the-table/

Comment: Is there a way of finding the time such as crdate or refdate when the pk was changed or is that only for when the column name changed?

Comment: Nothing I can find so far - may be worth asking on dba.stackexchange.com as those guys know more about that sort of area.  You could always write custom code to audit such things going forward.  Also if you have transaction logs I guess it would be possible (though probably painful) to hunt down such info in there?

Comment: Why the three `ident_` functions when all of that info is available in `sys.identity_columns`? The challenge with passing the name into those functions is if you have two tables with the same name in different schemas, those functions might return unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand; I wasn't familiar with that table.  Updating now. . .

Comment: @user2943263 here's a blog post on ddl auditing - http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/.  A better option's to have tight change control tied in with a good version control system; though that requires some setup / relies on people not circumventing the processes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate answer b/c I combined selects and added create and modified dates for sorting and schema name for possible dupes between schemas b/c key names are unique:

```
SELECT  schema_name = ( SELECT top 1 pk.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA FROM information_schema.table_constraints pk INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage c ON c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME WHERE pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME like '%' + i.name + '%')
        ,object_name(i.object_id) tableName, i.name indexName, c.name columnName, c.is_identity 
        ,ident_seed(object_name(i.object_id)) seed
        ,ident_incr(object_name(i.object_id)) increment
        ,ident_current(object_name(i.object_id)) lastAssignedId
        ,CreateDate = ( SELECT s.crdate FROM sysobjects s INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) cnt, xtype FROM sysobjects group by xtype) c ON  s.xtype = c.xtype WHERE s.name = i.name)
        ,ModifiedDate = (SELECT s.refdate FROM sysobjects s INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) cnt, xtype FROM sysobjects group by xtype) c on  s.xtype = c.xtype WHERE s.name = i.name)
FROM    sys.indexes i
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE   i.is_primary_key = 1 
ORDER BY    ModifiedDate, CreateDate DESC
```